# Vb.net Task-Based multiclient tcpserver

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, multitasking, tcpserver

I've got a tcpserver serving multiple clients at the same time using multithreading. It works very good but i have got an issue on memory management.

Up to 1500 clients may connect to the server and stay connected for hours and days.

So i am having "Out of memory trouble" because i MUST use 32bit operating system. So i want converting to 64bit os should stay as plan b.

What do you suggest me to do?

A task based asynchronous tcpserver serving multiclient?

Or keep going with multi threads and making reusable 1500 threads?

Thanks.

Comment: 1500 threads ?! You only need 2. One thread to receive the data and put it in a stack, an other thread to process the data. You could add a few more processing thread depending on what the CPU can support (1 thread per core).

Comment: Ok but it is an anti cheat server system like a proxy between 1500 game clients and a game server , i must listen 1500 clients and 1500 game server tcp socket , i want 2 threads too but how? How can i execute 1500 clients tcp packets at one thread? I m looking for this.

Comment: is there a way to wait for multiple clients stream at one thread? 

Dim stream As NetworkStream = vekil_client.GetStream()

Comment: A thread is needed if you are waiting for something or one thread per core to process something. I haven't done this in a while but I think [Asynchronous Socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example) is what you are looking for.

Comment: i suppose i should create new tasks not new threads huh?

Comment: Found it, I used [SocketAsyncEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs?view=netframework-4.8) in the past to handle a lot of clients. It's specialized for high-performance socket applications.

Comment: @the_lotus A true async workflow (as might happen when waiting on input from a socket) need not use threads for waiting.  Also see https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply changing "new thread" to "new task" solved my problem. Thank you all.

```
New Task(Sub() listen(tcp_client))
```

Comment: `New Task` is seldom the right thing to do, although I suppose it's possible that (in concert with code you don't show) it's the right thing for your specific use case.  Also see https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html and in general I would highly recommend the same blog's various articles on working with `Task`.